# Streaming API: subscribe callback function never called?

Tags: jquery, streaming-api, cometd

I've implemented a simple streaming api code for subscription to the push topic using a *callback function*. It's realy needed because the [official CotemD documentation](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/javascript_subscribe.html) expressly points to it:

> Calling subscribe() **does not mean** that you have completed the subscription with the server when function returns.
>
> If you want to be certain that the server received your subscription
>   request (or not), you can ... pass a callback function to subscribe()

Here is my subscribe function:

```
subscription = jQuery.cometd.subscribe('/topic/MyPushObject', 
                                        function(message){ handleMessage(message); }, 
                                        function(subscribeReply){
    // THIS PIECE OF CODE IS NEVER CALLED
    if (subscribeReply.successful){
        console.log('subscribe success');
    }
    else{
        console.log('subscribe failed');
    }
});
```

I can successfully subscribe to the push topic but the callback function is never called (no console log, no break points in browser).

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Did you create a PushTopic record and named it 'MyPushObject'?

Comment: @SImon Of course :) It all works fine, but the callback.

Answer (score 1):

The callback function feature has been added in CometD 2.8.0.

I am guessing that SalesForce uses an older version that does not have that functionality implemented.

The current CometD version is 3.0.4, and the updated CometD 3.0.x documentation is at [this address](http://docs.cometd.org/3/reference/).

The best thing is to ask SalesForce what exact CometD version they are using, and if it is old, to update it to newer versions - to provide bug fixes and more functionalities.